# Get only text in html tag with PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I try using [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to get only text --> 1 2 3 <-- in span tag

this my HTML code :

```html
<div class="pager rel clr">
  <span class="fbold prev abs large">
 <a class="link pageNextPrev {page:1}" href="SOME LINK">
   <span>«Prev</span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="item fleft">
    <a class="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24" href="SOME LINK">
    <span>1</span>
 </a>
  </span>
  <span class="item fleft">
    <span class="block br3 c41 large tdnone lheight24 current">     
    <span>2</span>
  </span>
  </span>
    <span class="item fleft">
      <a class="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24" href="SOME LINK">
        <span>3</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  <span class="fbold next abs large">
    <a class="link pageNextPrev {page:3}" href="SOME LINK">
      <span>Next»</span>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Edited I Create PHP code like this :

```
$e = $html->find('div.pager',0)->children();
foreach($e as $getnextpage=>$value){
    if(is_numeric($value->plaintext)){
        $yey = "This Number";
    }else{
        $yey = "Not Number";
    }
    echo "</br>";
    print $yey . "==>" . $value->plaintext . "</br>";
}
```

Result  :

Not Number==> 1

Not Number==> 2

Not Number==> Next»

How cek number...?

Comment: It looks like you want to iterate `$html->find('.item span')`

Comment: Edited , i use new php code

Comment: That's not even close to my suggestion. Ignore the other posters and do it my way.

Answer (score -1):

`div.pager` has `span` tags recursively so you are getting text for each `span` twice. If you want to fetch only page numbers then try this:

```
$html = str_get_html($curlData);
$e = $html->find('div.pager');

foreach($e as $getnextpage)
{
    foreach($getnextpage->find('span.fleft') as $get) {
            $innerSpan = $get->find('span');
            print($innerSpan);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have try that code before i ask. the problem its, another html tag in the webpage use span with same class to

Answer (score -1):

The only possible improvement here would be to get rid of a foreach by using something like so:

```
$html = str_get_html($curlData);
$e = $html->find('div.pager span.item a span');

foreach($e as $getnextpage)
{
   if(stripos($getnextpage->innertText,'next') == false && stripos($getnextpage->innertText,'prev')
   {
       $pages[] = $getnextpage->innerText;
   }
}
```

An alternative to the line

```
 if(stripos($getnextpage->innertText,'next') == false && stripos($getnextpage->innertText,'prev')
```

May be to check if it is an integer for example

```
if(is_int($getnextpage->innertText))
```

Another alternative to all of the above is that the spans you want have an anchor element surrounding them and only those ones with number have the class `block`. So you may for example be able to do:

```
$html = str_get_html($curlData);
$e = $html->find('div.pager span.item a.block span');

foreach($e as $getnextpage)
{
   $pages[] = $getnextpage->innerText;
}
```